# Android How sort and reverse sort in single Button clcik

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to sort and reverse sorting in single button click but i able to did only one, how can i implement this sorting and reverse sorting in consecutive button clicks.

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Comparator<Book> bb=Collections.reverseOrder();
                bk=Arrays.asList(books);
               Collections.sort(bk,bb);
                //Collections.shuffle(bk);
             // Collections.sort(bk);
                bookListView.invalidateViews();

        }
    });
```

Comment: You sort bk, but where do you actually set bookListView to show bk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Boolean` field whose initial value is true. In click handler of button, compare the  boolean field value, if it is `true` then do sort and set `false` to boolean field. If boolean value is `false` then do reverse and set `true` to boolean field.

```
boolean state=true;

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if(state) {
        //sort
        state=false;
     }
   else{
      //reverse
      state=true;
     }
    }
 });
```

Comment: The sort working only first header clicking with respect to first column data, when ever i click the second header column it's sorting with respect to first column data, not second column data, how can i do this issue.

Comment: @jalakam: along with "state" field you can also declare another field which holds the information about header. if header is 1st then assign value 1, if second header is selected then assign value 2 and so on.

Comment: How can i differentiate each Header information, below i  declare list of object like this,   'http://pastebin.com/XD6T0rFD'  from this how can i differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

All your code is doing is sorting the list in reverser order.

Collections.reverseOrder() returns a comparator to reverse.

And you pass bb comparator to Collections.sort method which reverse the collection.

From java doc, Sorts the specified list according to the order induced by the specified comparator.

You should sort it after you reverse it.

Comment: ya, but i sort and revers sort in consecutive click in same Button event, so i want to some conditions.